# Collection<T> does not Contain the all properties of ICollection interface

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

The `Collection<T>` class implements multiple interfaces, one of them being `ICollection`. The `ICollection` interface has 2 properties that are not implemented in `Collection<T>`.

In C# I believe you have to implement all the methods and properties of an Interface in the class that inherits it. So how is `Collection<T>` class allowed to get away with it?

Comment: Google **Explicit Interface Member Implementation**

Comment: Why do you say the properties are not implemented? I see them there http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs,281923b8611114ec the properties ICollection request are Count, SyncRoot and IsSynchronized, all of them are included

Comment: Which two properties do you think are not implemented?

Comment: FYI. Interfaces enforce implementation but not access level. Many of the MS libraries implement interfaces with `internal` access modifiers

Comment: @MDK, surely that would only work on an `internal` class: otherwise what happens when a client in another assembly wants to call the `internal` method via the interface?

Comment: @bto.rdz- Yeah in the link provided I can see the SyncRoot and IsSynchronized properties but in Visual Studio if you navigate to the Collection<t> class it doesn't display them. Also in Visual studio Collection<T> :  IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable Where as in that link Collection<T>: IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>

Comment: @MDK.  Can you give a concrete example?  If a class implements a public interface than all of the methods related to that interface must be public.

Comment: If you follow @chomba's suggestion, you'll find "When a member is explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through a class instance, but only through an instance of the interface."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called [explicitly implementing an interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). You can make a member not visible from the outside unless the object reference is converted to the interface type.

In the context of `Collection<T>` implementing `ICollection`, the interface in question defines legacy methods that existed before generics were introduced to C#. You could say it is the 'old ugly' way of managing collections.

The implementors decided to hide these ugly methods, while still providing its functionality to the caller.

```
var x = new Collection<int>();
object syncRoot = x.SyncRoot; //CS1061: Collection<int> does not contain a ....
ICollection collection = x;
syncRoot = collection.SyncRoot; //ok
```

Another scenario is where there is a conflict, usually due to external interfaces that are not well designed, and cannot be changed. An example:

```
interface IFile
{
    void Save();
}
interface IDatabaseRecord
{
    void Save();
}

class Customer : IFile, IDatabaseRecord
{
    public void Save()
    {
        //what to do here?
    }
}
```

This may be overcome by implementing the method explicitly:

```
class Customer : IFile, IDatabaseRecord
{
    void IFile.Save() { }
    void IDatabaseRecord.Save() { }
}
```

Note that this is almost always a code smell - it could confuse the caller into thinking a method is not present, or calling the wrong implementation (which caused this question to be posted in the first place).

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, along with it's uses. One last thing, although I cannot thing of a use but can we create an interface and then hide some of the properties or methods in a similar way.

Comment: An interface doesn't have access modifiers, it's basically how it is. So it's not possible to hide members

Comment: @Abhi.Net, I think they are actually not hidden. If you have a method that accepts `IFile` from the above scenario and you pass to it an instance of `Customer`, the argument of type `IFile` will have a `Save()` method. Even more, it will call `IFile.Save()`, if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

After reading your comments, the problem is that those properties are Explicitly implementated, as you can notice [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs,281923b8611114ec):

```
bool ICollection.IsSynchronized 
{
  get { return false; }
}
```

Notice it is not a common property like:

```
public bool IsSynchronized 
{
  get { return false; }
}
```

This basically means that the property is there but only when you cast it as `ICollection`

```
var c = new Collection<double>();
var casted = (ICollection) c;
var isSync = casted.IsSynchronized;
```

Comment: One last thing any idea why in Visual Studio I see Collection<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable Where as in that link Collection<T>: IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>

Comment: @Abhi.Net Play with the oink i gave you, use the search box and click in any type or interface you want to see its definition, it helps me alot

Answer (score 1):

Its uncle works for the framework and everybody just looks the other way.

Cast a `Collection<T>` as an `ICollection` and you will see that it implements the entire interface of `ICollection`.

Comment: What do you mean by "Its uncle works for the framework and everybody just looks the other way."? I am sure there will be a better reason

Comment: Nepotism. And class distinction.